# Is it possible to trace the origin of words 'স্বাধীনতা' in Bengali and 'स्वाधीनता' in Hindi?

Tags: etymology

Both the words sound similar and have similar meanings so my presumption is that they are derived from one or other or have a similar origin.

There is a slight difference in meaning as per my knowledge. The Bengali word 'স্বাধীনতা' pronounced 'sba-dhee-no-ta' means 'freedom' or 'liberty' where as the Hindi word 'स्वाधीनता' pronounced 'svaa-dhee-na-ta' means 'independence'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are both loanwords (tatsama) from Sanskrit.

https://dsalsrv04.uchicago.edu/cgi-bin/app/platts_query.py?qs=%D8%B3%D9%88%D8%A7%D8%AF%D9%87%D9%8A%D9%86%DB%8C&searchhws=yes